# How to get the Pelican version number from a template

Tags: pelican

I would like to add metadata in the HTML output, indicating that the page was generated from Pelican, and adding the Pelican version number. But I don't find how to get this number. I find no Pelican variable to have this information.

Calling the executable seems the only way?

```
% pelican --version
3.7.1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know if there is a more direct way to accomplish this, but you could add the following code in your configuration file (**pelicanconf.py** by default):

```
from pelican import __version__

PELICAN_VERSION = __version__
```

Now, you can reference this newly created variable in your HTML templates with Jinja2 syntax like so:

```
<p>I am using Pelican {{ PELICAN_VERSION }}.</p>
```

When you generate the content of your website to get a directory with static files (this is in `output/` by default), the content of the variable `PELICAN_VERSION` will be added like any other variable in your configuration file and you should be good to go.

Comment: As an example, you can refer to my GitHub repository where I added the relevant code. You can see the [configuration file](https://github.com/sglavoie/sglavoie.github.io-source/blob/460ef89770c709fd6b33426d825832dfee309bef/pelicanconf.py#L5-L7) and how this is integrated in the [HTML template](https://github.com/sglavoie/sglavoie.github.io-source/blob/460ef89770c709fd6b33426d825832dfee309bef/themes/SL/templates/base.html#L178).

Comment: Thanks, it works. I now have: <meta name="generator" content="Pelican (3.7.1)" />